# How can I optimize this expensive (0.5seconds+) binding?

Tags: binding, properties, ember.js

Any suggestions on how I can optimize this binding? It will never be set to, but I'm not sure how to convert it to oneWay bindings. What it does is keep track of all the colours that are used in an artwork. Colours can come from text or images (colours in an image are detected serverside, but that happens concurrently and does not affect the timing of this property).

```
coloursUsed: function() {
  var colours = new Ember.Set();
  var arts = [this.get('frontArt'), this.get('backArt')];
  arts.forEach(function(art) {
    if(Ember.isNone(art)){
      return;
    }
    if(! Ember.isEmpty(art.get('textArts'))) {
      colours.addEach(art.get('textArts').mapBy('colour'));        
      colours.addEach(art.get('textArts').mapBy('strokeColour'));
    }
    if(! Ember.isEmpty(art.get('imageArts'))) {
      var img_colours = art.get('imageArts').mapBy('colours');
      img_colours.forEach(function(img_colour_array){
        colours.addEach(img_colour_array);        
      })
    }
  });
  return colours.toArray();
}.property('frontArt.textArts.@each.colour',   'frontArt.textArts.@each.strokeColour',
           'backArt.textArts.@each.colour',    'backArt.textArts.@each.strokeColour',
           'frontArt.imageArts.@each.colours', 'backArt.imageArts.@each.colours'),
```

Comment: probably using a set to accumulate values is expensive, and I should accumulate an array and then unique when I have all the values.

Comment: I need to figure out how I can do this with arrayComputed and or reduceComputed and see if they are faster.

Comment: On average how man items does it have to iterate through?  for loops will be significantly faster than a foreach in large iterations, there are a plethora of things that can change.

Comment: @kingpin2k, the xxArts arrays are generally quite small -- single digits. The source of much of the multiplication of processing is that coloursUsed is used by a colour picker that shows the user palette separately from the general palette. So when the user changes a colour on an element, these interconnected properties take time to settle. Like 75K to 100K property updates. And the code that updates metamorphs runs 6 times, which I **think** means it is taking 6 rounds for the properties to "settle".